# IdentityServer3 with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, identityserver3

I hope this is something simple and easy to solve.
I have installed **IdentityServer3** in an existing project and managed to get the "in memory" stuff working.
Now I am hooking up to my **UserManager**. When I try to authenticate, I get this error:

> "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nCormar.Sql.Claim: : EntityType 'Claim' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.ClaimsIdentity: : EntityType 'ClaimsIdentity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.IdentityReference: : EntityType 'IdentityReference' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.Secret: : EntityType 'Secret' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.RefreshToken: : EntityType 'RefreshToken' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.Token: : EntityType 'Token' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.Scope: : EntityType 'Scope' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCormar.Sql.ScopeClaim: : EntityType 'ScopeClaim' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nClaims: EntityType: EntitySet 'Claims' is based on type 'Claim' that has no keys defined.\r\nClaimsIdentities: EntityType: EntitySet 'ClaimsIdentities' is based on type 'ClaimsIdentity' that has no keys defined.\r\nIdentityReferences: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityReferences' is based on type 'IdentityReference' that has no keys defined.\r\nSecrets: EntityType: EntitySet 'Secrets' is based on type 'Secret' that has no keys defined.\r\nRefreshTokens: EntityType: EntitySet 'RefreshTokens' is based on type 'RefreshToken' that has no keys defined.\r\nTokens: EntityType: EntitySet 'Tokens' is based on type 'Token' that has no keys defined.\r\nScopes: EntityType: EntitySet 'Scopes' is based on type 'Scope' that has no keys defined.\r\nScopeClaims: EntityType: EntitySet 'ScopeClaims' is based on type 'ScopeClaim' that has no keys defined.\r\n"

I thought this might be because I was missing a package, so I used **NuGet** to install **IdentityServer3.EntityFramework** but this didn't work. 
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was straight forward enough, you do have to have **IdentityServer3.EntityFramework**. I looked at the source and saw the migration classes, so I just simply added the entities to my **DbContext** like this:

```
public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClientClaim> ClientClaims { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClientSecret> ClientSecrets { get; set; }
public DbSet<Consent> Consents { get; set; }
public DbSet<Scope> Scopes { get; set; }
public DbSet<ScopeClaim> ScopeClaims { get; set; }
```

Then I did a `add-migration` and `update-database`. This created the tables for me and everything was tickity-boo